# How likely are the following events?

Tags: probability

Assume that in a married couple there is a probability of 0.8 that the
husband will still be alive in 20 years while the wife has a somewhat higher probability, 0.9. How likely
are the following events?

> Both are still alive in 20 years.
>
> $0.8 * 0.9=0.72$
>
> Neither of them is still alive in 20 years.
>
> $0.2*0.1=0.02$
>
> **At least one of them is still alive in 20 years.**
>   I'm not sure how to attempt the last part of the question. Any guidance will be appreciated. Do I minus the end result by 1?  So it would be $0.8+0.9-1=0.7$

Is it correct?

Comment: Assuming independence as you have, it would be $1-0.02$ since they cannot both die

Comment: The "subtract $1$" part is definitely _not_ correct. What if the husband had probability $0.4$ to be alive and the wife has probability $0.5$? What do you get for the "probability both are alive" in that case?

Comment: There is a solution with $0.8 + 0.9 - (\mathrm{something})$. It's explained in the answers and probably also in your textbook or course notes if you reviewed them. There is also an easier method suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of at least one of them being a live means that they are not both dead. What is the probability that they are not both dead?

Comment: @Leucippus It's clearly meant to be a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the event that the husband lives, and $B$ the event that the wife does, and assume these have independence.

Then the event that both are alive is $A\cap B$, that both are dead is $A^\complement\cap B^\complement$, and that at least one is alive is $A\cup B$.

You have been provided that $\def\P{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}\P(A)=0.8, \P(B)=0.9$.

And have correctly used $\P(A\cap B)=\P(A)\P(B)$ and $\P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)=(1-\P(A))(1-\P(B))$

---

You claim $\P(A\cup B)=\P(A)+\P(B)-1$ however, this is **not true**.

In fact, $$\begin{align}\P(A\cup B)&=1-\P((A\cup B)^\complement)\\&=1-\P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)\\&=1-(1-\P(A))(1-\P(B))\\&=1-(1-\P(A)-\P(B)+\P(A)\P(B))\\&=\P(A)+\P(B)-\P(A\cap B)\end{align}$$